# Display attributes of an has_many through connection

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I have an `invoice` which has_many `line_items` which belongs_to `products` too. On `invoice#show` I want to display all `line_items` of that `invoice` with the `name` of the associated `product`. Coming from Rails I have a hard time to connect the dots. `line_item.product.name` in the template doesn't work. How can I display the product`s name in that table?

**The application**

```
mix phoenix.new my_app
cd my_app
mix ecto.create
mix phoenix.gen.html Invoice invoices number
mix phoenix.gen.html Product products name price:integer
mix phoenix.gen.html LineItem line_items invoice_id:references:invoices 
                                         product_id:references:products 
                                         quantity:integer
mix ecto.migrate
```

**web/models/invoice.ex**

```elixir
defmodule MyApp.Invoice do
  use MyApp.Web, :model

  schema "invoices" do
    field :number, :string
    has_many :line_items, MyApp.LineItem
[...]
```

**web/controllers/invoice_controller.ex**

```elixir
[...]
def show(conn, %{"id" => id}) do
  invoice =
    Repo.get!(Invoice, id)
    |> Repo.preload([:line_items])

  render(conn, "show.html", invoice: invoice)
end
[...]
```

**web/templates/invoice/show.html.eex**

```html
<h2>Invoice <%= @invoice.number %></h2>

<table class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Product</th>
      <th>Quantity</th>

      <th></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
<%= for line_item <- @invoice.line_items do %>
    <tr>
      <td><%= line_item.product.name %></td>
      <td><%= line_item.quantity %></td>
    </tr>
<% end %>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to handle this case to add a `Ecto.Schema.has_many/3` `:through` option like so:

**web/models/invoice.ex**

```
defmodule MyApp.Invoice do
  # ...
  schema "invoices" do
    field :number, :string
    has_many :line_items, HasMany.LineItem
    has_many :products, through: [:line_items, :product]

    timestamps
  end
  # ...
end
```

Because the association runs through `:line_items`, you preload both associated `:line_items` and `:products` with a query like this:

**web/controllers/invoice_controller.ex**

```
def show(conn, %{"id" => id}) do
  invoice =
    Repo.get!(Invoice, id)
    |> Repo.preload([:products])

  render(conn, "show.html", invoice: invoice)
end
```

The docs provide some great examples regarding "has_many/has_one :through" associations: https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Schema.html#has_many/3